# How to create a screen wrapper with an object trail?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want the trail to roll over the screen as the object moves from top to bottom like a screen wrapper.
When the object reaches the bottom - If I change its position to the top of the screen, the trail too follows - showing the object traveled bottom to top, whereas I wish the trail to follow in a single direction i.e. downwards only.

How can this be achieved ?

I tried using trailrenderer's Clear() function when the object reaches the bottom and enable() function when the object position is changed to top, the Clear function removes the whole trail, which is not desired.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me - Put the transition of an object from bottom to top frame in the third axis i.e. the hidden axis, so that is not visible to our camera.